# How to set at least two characters in jQuery UI autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery autocomplete and would like to limit the showing results only when the user types at least 2 characters. How to do that?

Comment: `http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-minLength`. I found it in less than 30 seconds. How could you not?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

for the record:

The minimum number of characters a user has to type before the Autocomplete activates. Zero is useful for local data with just a few items. Should be increased when there are a lot of items, where a single character would match a few thousand items.

**Code examples**

Initialize a autocomplete with the minLength option specified.

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({ minLength: 0 });
```

Get or set the minLength option, after init.

```
//getter
var minLength = $( ".selector" ).autocomplete( "option", "minLength" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete( "option", "minLength", 0 );
```

minLengthIntegerDefault:1

[docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-minLength)

Answer (score 6):

```
$( "#myselectbox" ).autocomplete({ minLength: 2 });
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no minLength attribute. The attribute you are searching for is **minChars**.

see https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete