# rails 3.2 jquery autocomplete minlength

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, autocomplete, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am following the instructions to implement auto complete in a rails 3.2.11 application but I need to specify a minimum number of characters to type before the query triggers. THe jQuery API documentation has an attribute "minLength". I can't figure out how to implement this in a rails auto complete field tag. Here is my code for the field tag.

```
<%= autocomplete_field_tag 'unit', '', autocomplete_unit_identifier_subjects_path, :id_element => '#subject_id', :size => 75 %>
```

Here is the url to the instructions I am following.
https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106395/how-to-set-at-least-two-characters-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete

Comment: Not so, that page is pure jQuery. This is about a rails form helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, minLength doesn't work because of this code in autocomplete-rails.js, line 65 or so:

```
 search: function() {
      // custom minLength
      var term = extractLast( this.value );
      if ( term.length < 2 ) {
        return false;
      }
    },
```

You can change the '2' to whatever you want the minLength to be.

Comment: yes it will be overwritten but you can override the method in gem somewhere in your code probably in .rb file in `config/initializers`.

Comment: It seems like a serious omission to leave this important attribute out of the rails form helper.

Comment: well if you are interfering with the gem code then you have to do this or else each time you update your gem, you have to manually change the `autocomplete-rails.js` file. The former is good as it releases the point of manual updation with gem. However if you find more good approach to do the same then it will be interesting to know.

Comment: This is a little beyond me, how would I write the override method?

Comment: that may be your another rails question. Or you can try if find useful this one post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688853/how-to-override-a-class-method-of-the-gem-in-rails-application

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is looking for an updated answer, it appears you can now set minimum length with the attribute 'min-length'.

```
<%= autocomplete_field_tag 'group_name', '', group_autocomplete_path, 'placeholder' => 'Select a Job Number', 'size' => 35, 'class' => 'styled-select', 'data-auto-focus' => true, 'min-length' => 1 %>
```

Why its not 'minlength' as documented in jQuery autocomplete, I don't know..